# How to set up Firebase Database on React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to setup my Firebase Database and have already set up my collection on the firestore please see image:

[image: Firestore Image]

I've been following the docs and have setup my firebase app in a firebaseConfig.js file.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBWDFmAF4Bx7PpSvccF_ebRe2kBWGqj11c",
  authDomain: "recipegenerator-918a7.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "recipegenerator-918a7",
  storageBucket: "recipegenerator-918a7.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "743737873782",
  appId: "1:743737873782:web:8036f2ed1cae24f60d5657",
  measurementId: "G-Z9WK0Q0ML3"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app)
const recipes = collection.apply(db, 'recipe')
```

I am trying to use this in my App.js file to Save a Recipe

```
    import { recipes } from './components/firebaseConfig';
    import 'firebase/database';
    import { ref, set } from 'firebase/database'

    const saveRecipe = () => {
    set(ref(recipes, 'recipegenerator-918a7'), {
      recipe: {
      Ingredients:'ingredient 1',
      Instructions: "instruction 1"
      NutritionalInfomation: "Nutrition 1"
      Recipe Title: "title 1"
    })

    <Button title="Save Receipe" onPress={() => {saveRecipe()}}></Button>
```

However I get this error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore, js engine: hermes

I've tried multiple resources and tutorials to overcome this problem but I cannot seem to connect or update my Firebase Database from my React Native App. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems off:

```
const recipes = collection.apply(db, 'recipe')
```

Instead, it should be:

```
const recipes = collection(db, 'recipe')
```

Also see the Firebase documentation, like the example in the [getting started guide on adding data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9_2).